# SimpleSAMLphp custom authsource without password

Tags: php, authentication, browser, simplesamlphp

For one of our customers I need to write a custom authsource module. I allready set up SimpleSAMLphp as an Idp using various authsources like LDAP, SQLauth, etc. All of those authsources have in common that they use a login form and authenticate against the `sspmod_core_Auth_UserPassBase` class. This means that there will be a login form for username and password etc.

The special case right here is the following:

The SAML installation (IdP) is inside the companies network. If a user (inside of that network/authenticated via AD) visits a host that is inside that network, the username will be automatically injected in its browser and is available via `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and we have the guarantee, that the user is allready "validated".

This means we do not have to "authenticate" the user any more. We do not have to show a login form and just need to mark that user as authenticated.

Now I am a little stuck, because for my understanding it would be a little bit "overdosed" to write an own authsource that extends the default `UserPassBase` class. I would have to handle empty passwords and automatically forward/post from login form etc.

I guess there is a better way to handle that. The flow would be pretty simple:

SP redirects to IdP. The IdP "login page" reads `PHP_AUTH_USER` (no output like a login form), authenticates the user (without any further check) and redirects as expected if user was detected correctly. If the `PHP_AUTH_USER` could not be found in any way, the user will be redirected to some kind of error page.

Any ideas how to solve that the correct way? I guess I will have to write my own completely new authsource class that extends the base `SimpleSAML_Auth_Source` class? Maybe someone has an example for that situation before I am going to reinvent the wheel!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `exampleAuth:Static` [authsource](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/blob/master/modules/exampleauth/lib/Auth/Source/Static.php). It auto-logs you in as a specific user

```
'example-static' => array(
    'exampleauth:Static',
    'uid' => array('testuser'),
    'eduPersonAffiliation' => array('member', 'employee'),
    'cn' => array('Test User'),
),
```

You could create your own module like it, but instead of loading attributes from the `authsource` config, load them based on the username. and do something like

```
public function authenticate(&$state) {
    $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    if ($user) {
        $attributes = loadAttributesForUser($user);
        $state['Attributes'] = $attributes;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('No user found');
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!

Comment: @Marco / Patrick - I'm new to SimpleSamlPHP. can you please guide me where i should create this authenticate() function. I need to authenticate using custom credentials.